# How to replace the value for a "key" in a table?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have no programming experience, so I don't know what should I put in the title.

But please help me, this is a really simple matters, I just want to change ships['俾斯麦'] to ships['Bismarck'].

Example is below

**Database/Ship**

```
local ships = { }

----------------------------------------------

ships['俾斯麦'] = {
    index=1, country='Germany', class='Bismarck-class'
}

----------------------------------------------

return { ships=ships }
```

Then

**Special Data/Ship**

```
local data = require("Database/Ship")

data.ships['俾斯麦'] = 'Bismarck'

return data
```

Edit: How do I do this with gsub, example from other people code:

```
local function replaceShipName(name)
    name = name:gsub('俾斯麦', 'Bismarck')
    name= name:gsub('提尔比茨', 'Tirpitz')
    return name
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand your question: you have an rules for renaming like rename `'俾斯麦'` to `'Bismarck'`

```
local namingRules = {
    '俾斯麦' = 'Bismarck',
    '提尔比茨' = 'Tirpitz'
}

--do renaming for all data
local shipsData = data.ships
for key, value in pairs (shipsData) do
  local newKey = namingRules[key]
  if (newKey  ~= nil) then
    --if data should be renamed
    shipsData[newKey] = shipsData[key]
    shipsData[key] = nil
  end
end
```

So with this solution you can define naming using `namingRules` table. If you want to use gsub solution:

```
local shipsData = data.ships
for key, value in pairs (shipsData) do
  local newKey = replaceShipName(key) -- this is your replaceShipName function
  if (newKey ~= nil and newKey ~= key) then
    shipsData[newKey] = shipsData[key]
    shipsData[key] = nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I supposed need.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access the data in `data.ships['俾斯麦']` using `'Bismarck'` as key, just do

```
data.ships['Bismarck'] = data.ships['俾斯麦']
```

Comment: And don't forget to remove previous name with `data.ships['俾斯麦'] = nil` :)

Comment: How do I do this with gsub, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your edited question:

It doesn't make sense to use gsub here. Once you have stored something in a table with a certain key, it remains associated with that key until you store something else in the same table using the exact same key, or until the entire table gets garbage collected because you're not using it anymore.

(If you're using something called "weak tables" then the garbage collection part gets more complicated, but you're not using them here.)

For example:

```
local t = {}

t["a"] = "A value"
print(t["a"]) -- "A value"
print(t["b"]) -- nil

t["b"] = t["a"]
print(t["a"]) -- "A value"
print(t["b"]) -- "A value"

t["a"] = nil
print(t["a"]) -- nil
print(t["b"]) -- "A value"

t = nil -- You can't access the table now, so it will be garbage collected at some point
```